# Distinct write behaviour between Windows Server 2008 SP2 & Windows Server 2008 R2 on Azure

Tags: azure, iis-7, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

Consider the following scenario

I have one webrole writting a file into one folder /root/somefolder where root is the root of the site.

The webrole works with OsFamily="1" (Windows Server 2008 SP2), but fails writting the file with OsFamily="2" (Windows Server 2008 R2). Same package deployed on Azure.

I know I should use local storage and I know it's kindof antipattern writting files into the web folders. Anyway, let's say I am not proud of that piece of code and I am looking for a quick solution here. I promise I will do it right in the next future. Just when I have some free time (LOL).

I would like to avoid doing the problem worse (elevating the user account). I just wanna know how to enable write for that folder (avoiding a startup .bat would be nice). And of course, It will be awesome if someone could explain why IIS behaves distinct between OS versions.